# Disable zoom doesn't work correctly on safari ipad/iphone

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, meta-tags

I am using jquery mobile to develop an app.
I have disabled zoom for the entire app using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

And everything works fine, until I tap a text input in the app, to type, and the iPad/iPhone keyboard shows up, after this the pinch zoom gets re-enabled after the keyboard hides when done typing, even though the meta is still specified.

What am I doing wrong? I have searched a lot for a good answer and did not find anything specific.

Comment: which device did you test? i couldn't reproduce on iphone 5

Answer (score 0):

Remove: width=device-width

use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

The doc type is ? :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: doesn't change anything, problem still occurs

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>  is html, yes